# Azure Data Factory Pipeline Intermittent Error 2906

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have four ADF pipelines running on different schedules (1Hr, 2Hr, 6Hr and 1Day). Since yesterday they are having intermittent failures, reporting Error 2906, as follows:

{
    "errorCode": "2906",
    "message": "Package execution failed.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "%package name%"
}

I'm unclear in the error however given that it has been working just fine up until yesterday, and then yesterday it succeeds and then fails intermittently, is there any advice on how/where to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say this is the definitive answer, however I suspect the DB was merely under strain performance-wise. The problem appears to have disappeared now.